# PHP File protection mechanism crashes because of FF

Tags: php, firefox, http-authentication

I have the following problem:
I have several image galleries which should only be visible to registered user.
The images are in one directory per gallery, each dir with a long, cryptic name.
But if you know the link, you can access the images without authentication.
Since I am using PHP on the server side, a simple approach would be "readfile" with .htaccess, but I do not want to pass hundreds of images through php.

So I tried a different approach: I used basic http authentication, with a dynamic generated .htpasswd file, containing access data for each loggedin user, which is resetted after 24 hours and after every logout of a user, so links on the images are broken after max. 24 h.
But I do not want the user to type in the cryptic, auto-generated username and password for this authentication, so I use urls like this:
`http://username:password@path-to-image`
That works perfectly in chrome, but in FF, when I want to include more than one image, the dialog to enter username and password appears for some of the subdirs of the protected one.

An example: I have the following dirs:
/gallery/one/
/gallery/two/
The protection is in an .htaccess file in /gallery/

And sometimes firefox only loads the images from /gallery/one/, sometimes only from /gallery/two/, sometimes none of these, sometimes both. If he doesnt load at least one of these, he asks to enter your username and password.
I cannot explain this behaviour, and I havent found a solution to make FF safely accept more than one url with username and password in it without asking.
Is there a solution for this problem, or do you have any other way to safely protect files on the server?
Thanks in advance.

PS: I have heard of mod-xsendfile, but it cannot be installed on my webhost.

Comment: What was wrong with the original method `pass images through php`? i use the same method for every image inc template files css, js, swf ect and ever run into problems. perhaps it was the code and not the method.

Comment: I simply do not want to use it, because it is slow if you have hundreds of image, and it increases the server load which is not good on shared webspace

Comment: Well loading hundreds of images in a single pop would always have server load which ever method you choose, have some pagination with lazy loading whereas only images in view are loaded.

Comment: It is lazy loaded (about 42 thumbs a page), but I simply want to find out why the other method with the http auth does not work, because I feel there has to be a fix for that, maybe someone knows one...